# Why is the test in my ColorFunction not behaving as expected?

Tags: plotting, color

In my code I have a `ColorFunction` that is meant to highlight all values of $f(x)$ that are greater than $x$

```
ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= #2, Red, Black] &)
```

so that, for example, the parts of the plot of $3\sin^3(x)$ in the figure below that lie above the line $y=x$ should be red, and the parts below, black, but that's not what I get:

[image]

What am I missing? I expect I've make some simple (and embarrassing) mistake here, but I'm not seeing it.

---

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[{u, 3 Sin[u]^3}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= #2, Red, Black] &), 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01]}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[x, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}]]
```

Comment: Related: [(13046)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13046/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `ColorFunctionScaling->False`

```
 Show[
   ParametricPlot[{u, 3 Sin[u]^3}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
        ColorFunction -> (If[#1 >= #2, Red, Black] &), 
        PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01]}, PlotRange -> All, 
        ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   ], 
   Plot[x, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the black/red boundary isn't very precise. Increasing the number of `PlotPoints` to, say, 200 helps:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, at least I was right about "dumb and embarrassing".

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's just one of those days...