# How to use the same color bar for different DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed color scale in multiple density plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13046/fixed-color-scale-in-multiple-density-plots)

I want to normalize different `DensityPlot`s. The scale for the color bar is from 0 to 1. I can do the job in Origin after I get all the data, but I think Mathematica can do it also. I am not very familar with `ColorFunctionScaling`--could you show me an example?

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you want/provide a test case, and show what you've tried already? As it is, this question is likely to be closed. This forum is not intended as an extension of the documentation, I'm afraid, so if you simply want additional examples, you will be better off to ask on *MathGroup* or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [ColorFunctionScaling](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) to avoid re-scaling of the [ColorFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html).