# BarLegend problem when rescaling color of multiple vectorplot

Tags: legending, plotting

I want to make multiple vector plot **at same color scale with same BarLegend**. Similar posts are [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13046/4742), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/why-does-plotrange-in-densityplot-have-no-effect)

I made a minimal example to show the problem I encountered

```
data = {Table[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}], 
   Table[{3 x, 3 y}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}]};
normData = Map[Norm, data, {3}];
min = Min[normData];
max = Max[normData];

Table[
 ListVectorPlot[data[[i]],
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}],
  VectorColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {min, max}]]],
  VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

You can see the color scaling of two vectorplot is right.

**But the BarLegend is wrong.**

How to fix it?

Comment: Related part of the documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html#1239470157

Comment: @Karsten7. Hi, Karsten7. What do you mean? Set BarLegend to automatic? But that won't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest workaround is to use

```
Table[Labeled[
  ListVectorPlot[data[[i]], PlotRange -> All, 
   VectorColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {min, max}]]], 
   VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300],
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}, ImageSize -> 300],
  {{Right, Center}}
  ], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Out1]

---

This is probably the correct way to specify the `BarLegend` for the given situation:

```
Table[ListVectorPlot[data[[i]], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {min, max}]] &, {min, max}}], 
  VectorColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {min, max}]]], 
  VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image: Out2]

Alternatively one can add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` to `BarLegend`. This option is undocumented for `BarLegend` and will be highlighted in red in the FE.

```
Table[ListVectorPlot[data[[i]], PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
  VectorColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {min, max}]]], 
  VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 300], {i, 1, 2}]
```

---

#### Explanation:

You specified the `BarLegend` in the format you wanted it to be displayed.
However, as stated in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html#1239470157),

> `BarLegend` automatically picks up values of `ColorFunction` and
>   `ColorFunctionScaling`.

For your specific case this means that your `BarLegend` gets replaced by

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0., 12.7279}}, Legending`LegendDump`options$2394]
```

with `` Legending`LegendDump`options$2394 `` being an internal value that picked up `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` from the rest of the input (the number at the end will be different each time the input is evaluated) and subsequently `BarLegend` becomes

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0.`, 12.727922061357857`}}, 
 Sequence[LabelStyle -> {}, LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
  Charting`TickSide -> Right, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]
```

[image: OutPNG]

Comment: Thank you so much, Karsten 7. That explained all. The undocumented option for BarLegend is really handy to fix this. How do you know this option?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you consider the min and max of the individual tables within normTable.

```
min=Map[Min,normData];max=Map[Max,normData];

Table[ListVectorPlot[data[[i]],PlotRange->All,PlotLegends ->BarLegend[{"Rainbow",{min[[i]],max[[i]]}}],VectorColorFunction ->Function[{x,y,vx,vy,n},ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[n, {min[[i]], max[[i]]}]]],VectorColorFunctionScaling->False,ImageSize->300],{i,1,2}]
```

Comment: Hi, demm. Thank you for answering. But that is not what I want. I want two plots have the same scale and same BarLegend