# Plotting a row of ListDensityPlot with same bar legend

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I would like to plot a row of three (maybe 4 or 5) ListDensityPlot and the export it as .eps (to use in a paper written in Latex). I want the same bar legend for all plots. Something like what is  described here:

[Fixed color scale in multiple density plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13046/fixed-color-scale-in-multiple-density-plots)

but with the bar legend included. And also with each picture having its own axis labels.

Here is a sample:

```
data1 = Table[{ll, kk, RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 1, 
100}];

data2 = Table[{ll, kk, 0.95*RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 
1, 100}];

data3 = Table[{ll, kk, 0.80*RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 
1, 100}];

g1 = data1 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
ListDensityPlot[#, FrameLabel -> {Style["x1", 20], Style["y1", 20]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0] &

g2 = data2 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
ListDensityPlot[#, FrameLabel -> {Style["x2", 20], Style["y2", 20]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0] &

g3 = data3 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
ListDensityPlot[#, FrameLabel -> {Style["x3", 20], Style["y3", 20]},
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 8, LegendLabel -> Style["z", 20], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300], Right]] &
```

I tried to glue them using:

```
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2, g3}, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

but there is an issue with the size of the last Plot.

What could I do? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data1 = Table[{ll, kk, RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 1, 
    100}];
data2 = Table[{ll, kk, 0.95*RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 
    1, 100}];
data3 = Table[{ll, kk, 0.80*RandomReal[{ll, kk}]}, {kk, 1, 100}, {ll, 
    1, 100}];
```

---

```
g1 = data1 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
   ListDensityPlot[#, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["x1", 20], Style["y1", 20]}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     ImageSize -> 300] &;

g2 = data2 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
   ListDensityPlot[#, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["x2", 20], Style["y2", 20]}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     ImageSize -> 300] &;

g3 = data3 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
   ListDensityPlot[#, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["x3", 20], Style["y3", 20]}, 
     FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[20], AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     ImageSize -> 300
     ] &;
g4 = data3 // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
  ListDensityPlot[#, Frame -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
    AspectRatio -> 4, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 100}}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> {100, 300}
    , PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 8, LegendLabel -> Style["z", 20], 
       LegendMarkerSize -> 250], {0.55, 0.55}]
    ] &
```

---

**Using `GraphicsRow`:**

```
GraphicsRow[{g1, g2, g3, g4}, Spacings -> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, 0}, 
 Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 1150]
```

[image]

**Using `Frame`:**

```
Framed[Grid[{{g1, g2, g3, g4}}, Frame -> None], 
 Background -> Lighter@Yellow, FrameStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```